# Не могу выполнить запрос на удалённый сервер, всегда 400

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование, http, post, request

Есть сайт booking.uz.gov.ua/ru/   где можно проверять наличие билетов.
Если делать запрос из браузера - запрос проходит нормально пока жив  уникальный токен (передаётся в заголовках). Если делать с какой-либо другой страницы - срабатывает CORS и выполнить запрос невозможно. 
Это не проблема, ведь можно использовать свой сервер, либо приложение postman для браузера хром например.

Я полностью скопировал все заголовки и тело запроса в Postman, но в ответ всегда приходит ошибка 400.
Что я мог делать не так и могли ли они каким-либо образом (не считая cors) запретить запросы даже из постмана и каких-либо других приложений?

Comment: Берите Wireshark и сранивайте в нем ваш запрос и оригинальный. Могут палить referer, могут accept, вариантов масса!

Comment: То есть несмотря на то, что я скопировал ВСЕ заголовки, включая и реферера и аксепт и всё остальное, в итоге запросы все равно могут отличаться?

Comment: Я вот тут тоже копировал accept, но когда посмотрел в Wireshark увидел ДВА таких заголовка: один мой, и один который инструмент добавлял.

Comment: Инструмент Postman? То есть он ко всему прочему еще свой заголовк туда засовывал? А еще отличия были? Я сейчас тоже просматриваю как раз отличия

Comment: Другой инструмент. Раз мой так косячил - ваш тоже может косячить. Без анализа траффика у вас будет гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за подсказки.